# How to do grouping of items in winjs list view

Tags: windows, winjs

I want to do  grouping of. List view items in winjs .can any one suggest me

Comment: What have you tried? Msdn has documentation on grouping options, along with tutorials. Asking for links isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your basic data in a WinJS.Binding.List, call that list object's [createGrouped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700742.aspx) method, which returns a now-grouped projection. You then use that projection's dataSource property as the itemDataSource for the ListView. You can also use that projection's groups.dataSource property as a groupDataSource for the ListView's groups.

See [How to group items in a ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465464.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my codeShow app that includes a super simple example in the ListViews demo. The app is at http://aka.ms/codeshowapp and the full source code is at http://codeshow.codeplex.com.